# Degree of line bundles is additive on curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

In Hartshorne (among other places), it is used that on a nonsingular curve $C$, the degree of line bundles is additive. That is,

$$\mbox{deg}_C(L_1 \otimes L_2) = \mbox{deg}_C(L_1)+ \mbox{deg}_C(L_2).$$

I can't see why, nor find a reference for this. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks.

Edit: definition of degree I'm using is taking the associated Weil divisor $\sum_{P\in C}\eta_P P$, then taking the degree to be $\sum \eta_P$.

Comment: The $\LaTeX$ for tensor product is \otimes. Presumably you mean $\deg(L_1) + \deg(L_2)$ on the right? What definition of degree are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I've long had $\otimes$ renamed to \tensor.
The definition I'm using is taking the associated Weil divisor $\sum_{P\in C}\eta_P P$, then taking the degree to be $\sum \eta_P$.

Comment: Do you know how to compute $\mathcal{O}(\sum n_P P)\otimes \mathcal{O}(\sum m_Q Q)$?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't :/

Comment: @Hock: the map from line bundles to divisors is a group homomorphism.

Comment: Just to clarify (it is very late here, but I can't sleep...), I may write $\deg_C(L_1 \otimes L_2) = \deg_C(D_1 + D_2) = \deg_C(D_1) + \deg_C(D_2) = \deg_C(D_1) + \deg_C(D_2)$, where $D_1, D_2$ are the corresponding Weil divisors?

Comment: @Hock: yes. ${}$

Comment: Thanks very much. I can sleep easy now!